# Suppress print from summary on auto.arima model

Tags: r, printing

I checked the function `invisible` and `quietly` from the `purrr` package, but I couldn't work it out. I'm sorry if it has already been asked.

I have something like this:

```
library(forecast)

mod <- auto.arima(AirPassengers)
summary_mod <- summary(mod) # this always makes a print of the summary
rmse <- summary_mod[2]
```

I wanted to save the rmse from the model, but with `summary` I can't find a way to kill the auto print function.

I've tried:

```
summary_mod <- invisible(summary(mod))

library(purrr)
summary_mod <- quietly(summary(mod))
```

I've found out that I can use:

```
accuracy(mod)[2]
# [1] 10.84619
```

But I was wondering if I can get a solution that suppress the `print` function, just for possible future needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could `sink()` the output, like this:

```
mod <- auto.arima(AirPassengers)
sink("~temp.txt") #create temp file (you might replace ~ with desired working directory)
summary_mod <-summary(mod) #does not print anything now in R console, only in temp.txt file
sink(NULL) #use this to stop sinking the output
rmse <- summary_mod[2] #this still works now
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `capture.output`.

```
summary_mod <- capture.output(summary(mod))[14]
```

Comment: Almost, I've seen this solution, but this will change how I access the rmse, because now I have a long string, instead of a `numeric`.